# Apache2 folder is lost

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.2

I have removed the folder `/etc/apache2` to reset its configuration, but when I reinstall Apache2 it is not coming back. Could anybody please explain this to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apache2.2-common packages contain config. Reinstall apache2.2-common:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install apache2.2-common
```

or use autoremove(remove satisfy dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: This restores conf files, but you're still missing mods and default sites. Running 'apt-get --reinstall install apache2.2-common -o DPkg::options::="--force-confmiss"' seems to restore those.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing

`apt-get --reinstall install apache2.2-common -o DPkg::options::="--force-confmiss"`

This will reinstall all configuration files from apache2.2-common that are missing.

Just reinstalling the package will not reinstall the configuration files.